# How can i check SMS Delivery Report. While send SMS in background

Tags: android, kotlin, sms

I amd creating an app which is sending sms in background. But just in case of MI(Redmi) phones. i can not get any Delivery report. But its working fine on all other phones can anybody please help me i post my code here.

```
if (readSmsPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
val sManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager

             val infoSim = sManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(getSimSlot?.toInt()!!)!!

                    SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(infoSim.subscriptionId).
                            sendTextMessage( to , "", text,sentPI, sentPI)
                }

            }
```

// And this is my broadcast with pending intent

```
  val sendReceiverIntent  = sendSmsIntent()

    val sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)

    registerReceiver(sendReceiverIntent,IntentFilter("SMS_DELIVERED"))
```

Comment: do you getting any error?

Comment: can you post some more code,

Comment: @RajasekaranM I got no Error. My Broadcast not run ( Not enter in OnReceive )

Comment: @ManojPerumarath ok I am just uploading receiver left code are alrady posted

Comment: Please delete the comment and add this to your question

Comment: do you tested on below android 6 devices?

Comment: No actually the app is only for Lollipop devices and the problem is only in MI (Xioami) phones